# ¿Como accedo al evento clik de un boton que esta en un User Control desde un Form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, usercontrol

Tengo un `UserControl` con un botón (y varias cosas mas, pero lo importante aquí es ese boton). En ejecución, por alguna acción, el programa coloca este `UserControl` en un `FlowLayoutPanel` del `Form`, una vez puesto este `UserControl`, necesito que cuando el usuario aprieta el botón en cuestión del `UserControl` haga ciertas acciones en el `Form`.

Lo normal seria que en la parte de diseño al hacer "doble click" se genere automáticamente el evento clik en el `UserControl`, esto lo hace, pero necesito tener ese evento `Click` en el `Form` y no en el `UserControl`.

Comment: Si miras este documento [Custom Controls in Visual C# .NET](https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html) detenidamente puedes realizar eso que pides, es muy útil, traduce el texto con el traductor que gustes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Poner el botón como `public`(puedes hacerlo desde las propiedades del botón, cambiando `Modifiers` de `Private`a `Public`). De esa manera, podrás suscribirte al evento desde el form, haciendo algo como `flowLayoutPanel.usercontrol.boton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.boton_Click);`
2. Crear un evento personalizado en tu `UserControl`, dispararlo cuando se pulse el botón en él y suscribirte a dicho evento personalizado desde tu formulario.

**editado**

Parece por tu comentario que el problema además de lo que indicas es que los controles de usuario les estás añadiendo en tiempo de ejecución. En ese caso, lo que debes hacer para poder suscribirte al evento `Click` del botón es primero buscar los controles de usuario accediendo a la propiedad `Controls` del `FlowLayoutPanel`, para posteriormente recorrer cada uno de ellos y suscribirte al evento. Sería algo así:

```
var controles=this.flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<tuControldeUsuario>();
foreach (var controlUsuario in controles)
{
    controlUsuario.boton.Click += ControlUsuario_Click;
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por responder. El problema de la opcion 1, es que al acceder de esta forma flowLayoutPanel.usercontrol.boton.Click no se podria porque el usercontrol se va añadiendo dinamicamente en el flowlayout, entonces no lo reconoce en el tiempo cero de ejecucion del programa, hasta que se cree. Entonces estoy como el huevo o la gallina.

Comment: @yerald eso no sería una problema. Puedes buscar el usercontrol en tiempo de ejecución accediendo a la propiedad `Controls` del `FlowLayoutPanel`: `var controles = flowpanel.Controls.OfType<usercontrol>()`. Esto te daría una lista de todos los controles de tipo `usercontrol` y recorriendoles puedes suscribirte al evento click del boton

Comment: Pikoh me sirvio tu respuesta con ese codigo que pusiste ahi, justo lo que necesitaba amigo. Gracias!